# How to create 3 buttons in java swing to take 1/3 of the panel that they are added to?

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager

```
private JPanel createControlPanel() {
    JPanel ctrl = new JPanel();
    addBorder(ctrl,"Controls");
    //add 3 buttons here

    return ctrl;
    }
```

I wanna create those 3 buttons and add them to ctrl

Comment: Try  `JPanel ctrl = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1,3))`

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/grid.html. The buttons will appear the order you call the add method on your panel

Comment: you could use a box layout also: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/BoxLayout.html

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation :

```
GridLayout experimentLayout = new GridLayout(1,3);
compsToExperiment.setLayout(experimentLayout);

compsToExperiment.add(new JButton("Button 1"));
compsToExperiment.add(new JButton("Button 2"));
compsToExperiment.add(new JButton("Button 3"));
```

[Doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/grid.html)